# How to use stripe library on tsx files. Getting error

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, tsx

I have a project which is on react but files are not .js instead they are .tsx and I am trying to use stripe library but keep getting error.

[image: error screen shot]

I have tried few different libraries which help setting up stripe but I am keep getting stuck on this errr.

Please help or direct me to correct library which help me setup stripe.

my codes are

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
import axios from "axios";


function handleToken(token, addresses) {
    console.log(token, addresses);
  }

export default function Webinar() {

  return (
    <div className="container">

       <StripeCheckout stripeKey = "mykey"
            token={handleToken}
            name="Tesla Roadster"
            billingAddress
            shippingAddress
            />

    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is saying that your Typescript repo is now `strict` mode enabled which forces you specify the typing. If you wish to keep it silent, you can simply switch it to `false` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": false,
    // ...
  }
}
```

Change your function `handleToken` to be a variable with has the same type of your component prop as following:

```js
const handleToken: StripeCheckout['props']['token'] = (token) => {
  // You can receive hint from token type here
}
```

Comment: Man, you are a life saver :-)

Comment: Haha :) Glad to hear it helped

Comment: Now I am stuck to the next one I am getting this

Comment: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<StripeCheckoutProps>): StripeCheckout', gave the following error.
    Type '(token: any, addresses: any) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(token: Token) => void'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StripeCheckoutProps, context?: any): StripeCheckout', gave the following error.
    Type '(token: any, addresses: any) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(token: Token) => void'.

Comment: It looks like the `token` prop is a function which takes only 1 argument called `Token`.  I'll drop you another hint so you don't have to specify the token argument directly.